# How to notify no of databases added in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, push-notification

I created a database of adding employees now i need to notify(push notification) the user that these many records have been added in their database.To show the push notification i am using an text view. how can i make that help is appreciated.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not the push notification it is **Notification**

Check this link : http://www.anddev.org/show_notification_in_statusbar-t1019.html

Here is the code for show Notification.

```
package org.anddev.android.statusbarnotificator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class StatusbarNotificator extends Activity {

        private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        private int YOURAPP_NOTIFICATION_ID;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get the notification manager service.
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        /* Show a sample notification when the first button was clicked. */
        findViewById(R.id.btn_showsample).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                StatusbarNotificator.this.showNotification(
                                                R.drawable.tinyandroid,
                                                R.string.notif_short,
                                                R.string.notif_detailed,
                                                false);
                        }
        });

        /* Clear the notification. */
        findViewById(R.id.btn_clear).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                StatusbarNotificator.this.mNotificationManager.cancel(YOURAPP_NOTIFICATION_ID);
                        }
        });
    }

    private void showNotification(int statusBarIconID, int statusBarTextID, int detailedTextID, boolean showIconOnly) {
        // This is who should be launched if the user selects our notification.
        Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this, StatusbarNotificator.class);

        // This is who should be launched if the user selects the app icon in the notification.
        Intent appIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.VIEW_ACTION,
                        Uri.parse("http://www.anddev.org"));

        // choose the ticker text
        String tickerText = showIconOnly ? null : this.getString(statusBarTextID);

        mNotificationManager.notify(
                   YOURAPP_NOTIFICATION_ID, // we use a string id because it is a unique
                                                      // number.  we use it later to cancel the
                                                      // notification
                   new Notification(
                       this,                        // our context
                       statusBarIconID,             // the icon for the status bar
                       tickerText,                  // the text to display in the ticker
                       System.currentTimeMillis(),  // the timestamp for the notification
                       "anddev.org - Notification", // the title for the notification
                       getText(detailedTextID),     // the details to display in the notification
                       contentIntent,               // the contentIntent (see above)
                       R.drawable.icon,                         // the app icon
                       "anddev",                                        // the name of the app
                       appIntent));                 // the appIntent (see above)
    }
}
```